# What is a Sexy Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, I call it a Sexy Phrase™. [image]

Text-only version in CSV form:

```
"Loaded Ohio","Amazed Oatcake"
"Cuban Smack","Swag Pelecan"
"Alchemical Bonanza","Pagan Mailbag"
"Killer Gladius","Cider Fox"
"Acid Cable","Precambrian Beaverpelt"
"Alcoholics Alcoholised","Lakeshore Masochism"
"Estonian Dairymaids","Marine Teacup"
"Misraised Hamsters","Pigman Nemesis"
"Sinless Gooseboy","Radish Girls"
"Hyperlogical Persuasion","Glitch Bonding"
"Baked Clam","Flab Dance"
"Jackhammer Heartbreak","Lice Barn"
"Mammoth Flusher","Hair Lady"
"Lysol Potion","Iodized Gallbladder"
```

Comment: I added a textual version. Feel free to remove if it in fact that's wrong somehow (e.g., details of typeface are critical).

Comment: Pelecan or Pelican?

Comment: Pelecan is correct.

Comment: But Pelecan isnt even a word

Comment: It’s an archaic form of pelican. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/pelecan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These phrases have this property:

> Take the word values using A=1 - Z = 26 gives:
>  Sexy Phrase™: Loaded → 12 + 15 + 1 + 4 + 5 + 4 = 41 and Ohio → 15 + 8 + 9 + 15 + 0 = 47
>  Not: Amazed → 1 + 13 + 1 + 26 + 5 + 4 = 50 and Oatcake → 15 + 1 + 20 + 3 + 1 + 11 + 5 = 56
>
>  Similarly, for the remaining pairs, as these six lines comparisons show:
>  Cuban Smack → 41 and 47, Swag Pelecan → 50 and 56
>  Alchemical Bonanza → 67 and 73, Pagan Mailbag → 39 and 45
>  Killer Gladius → 67 and 73, Cider Fox → 39 and 45
>  Acid Cable → 17 and 23, Precambrian Beaverpelt → 100 and 106
>  Alcoholics Alcoholised → 97 and 103, Lakeshore Masochism →  94 and 100
>  Estonian Dairymaids → 97 and 103, Marine Teacup → 60 and 66
>
>  The sums go up by six with the first pair prime. Not sexy pairs go up by six but are not both prime.

They are called a Sexy Phrase™ because

> [Sexy prime pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime) are prime numbers that differ by 6. The name is from the Latin word for six: *sex*.